# how to implement OpenID Connect from a private provider in the c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, postman, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that needs to integrate OpenID Connect authentication from a **Private OpenID Connect (OIDC) Provider**, and the flow has the following steps:

1. user click sign-in
2. it will redirect the user to the private OIDC site for authentication using the below `HTTP GET` request:
   [image]
3. after successful login in the private OIDC site, it will redirect back to my site and get the uri with a `code` result showing as below:
   [image]
4. then i will need to use the `code` from the above and make an `HTTP POST` call to the private ODIC token endpoint to get the access token for this user.

**So, my `questions #1` is: how to implement this in the c# asp.net app?**

Also, I tried this in Postman "Get New Access Token", and I got the token.

as you can see after I supply all the parameters and click Request Token, it popup the login winnow,
[image]
after successful sign in ,it shows the token
[image]

**my `questions #2` is: similar to question #1, is there anyway to implement this in c# asp.net app?**
*like in a asp.net mvc app, add a link-button with the url in the 1st image, when user clicks it will redirect it back to myapp with the `code`, and then use this code to make HTTP POST call in the **stpe3**.*

Comment: Checkout this example: https://github.com/curityio/example-dotnet-openid-connect-client

Comment: @TravisSpencer please post your comment as answer, looks like it will be the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find an [open source example of this on GitHub](https://github.com/curityio/example-dotnet-openid-connect-client). The license of that is very permissive, and it's well documented. I've used it in various workshops and trainings, so most of the bugs have been worked out. I would advise you to dig into that. For completeness though, I'll describe the general process here, and use that as the basis for explaining.

Any Web application implementing the OpenID Connect code flow will include two parts:

1. The start of the flow and
2. The handling of the callback

The application that perform these two things is called a "client" or "relying party". The thing that this client communicates with using the OpenID Connect protocol is called an OpenID Connect Provider (OP) and is often also referred to as an Identity Provider (IdP).

The first part of the client implementation will show a view that contains a button. This button will be the typical "login" or "sign in" button. Note that this is optional, and the application may immediately redirect the user to the OP if it detects that the user doesn't have a session. Given your question above, however, this won't be the case for you, and the client will start by rendering a view that shows such a button. The view might look something like this:

```html
<div>
    @if(Session.Count == 0) {
        <p>
            This is a demo application to demonstrate the use for OAuth2 
            and OpenID Connect. 
        </p>

        <p>
            Pressing Sign In will redirect you to @ViewData["server_name"] 
            and authorize the application to access your profile info. The 
            data will only be used to demonstrate the possibilities of the 
            OpenID Connect protocol and will not be stored. Be sure to 
            revoke access when you are satisfied.
        </p>
        <div>
            <a href="/login">Sign In</a>
        </div>
    } else {
      // ...
    }
</div>
```

This view would be rendered by a very basic controller that is wired up in the routing configuration established in `Global.asax.cs`. When the sign in button is clicked, the OpenID Connect parts start. The controller that handles this request would simply redirect to the OP's authorization endpoint. This might look like this, in the most basic case:

```cs
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    private static string start_oauth_endpoint = Helpers.Client.Instance.GetAuthnReqUrl();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect(start_oauth_endpoint);
    }
}
```

The interesting part is how the authorization endpoint is obtained. This could be hard-coded, defined in `Web.config`, or obtained from the metadata of the OP. In the example I referenced above, it fetches the OP's metadata on app start. This is done in `AppConfig` located in the `App_Start` directory of the Web app. This performs an HTTP GET request to the issuer ID (located in `Web.config`) with `/.well-known/openid-configuration`). The reason for fetching this metadata on app start rather than putting all of it in configuration is to reduce the coupling of the OP and client.

The redirection performed in the snipped above will have a few important query string parameters. Some of these will be known at design-time, and will be hard coded. Others will be configured in `Web.config`. Some will be dynamically computed at run-time. These are listed below:

`client_id`

The client ID of this MVC Web app.

`response_type`

The response type the OP should use. This will always be `code` in your case.

`scope`

The scope of access that the client is requesting. This will include at least `openid`.

`redirect_uri`

The redirect URI where the OP should send the user to after they authenticate and authorize the client.

Other request parameters can also be sent. To help you figure out which to send, and the effect they have on the flow, checkout [oauth.tools](https://oauth.tools). This is like "Postman for OAuth and OpenID Connect". It's fantastic; you'll love it. There, you can form all sorts of OAuth and OpenID Connect flows with their various parameters.

Once this redirect is made to the OP, the user will authenticate. The user may also have to consent to the client's access to their protected resources. In any event, the OP will redirect the user to the callback after that. This is the second part of the implementation.

Here, we'll have a `CallbackController` (or something along those lines). It will look like this (in its simplest form):

```cs
public class CallbackController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            string responseString = Helpers.Client.Instance
                .GetToken(Request.QueryString["code"]);

            SaveDataToSession(responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Session["error"] = e.Message;
        }

        return Redirect("/");
    }
}
```

The important part of this snippet is that it's obtaining the `code` from the query string, and making an HTTP POST request to the OP's token endpoint (which was also located by parsing the OP's metadata). If this succeeds, it will save the response in the session for later use. The `GetToken` method will look something like this:

```cs
public String GetToken(String code)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
        { "client_id", client_id},
        { "client_secret", client_secret },
        { "code" , code },
        { "redirect_uri", redirect_uri}
    };


    HttpClient tokenClient = new HttpClient();
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = tokenClient.PostAsync(token_endpoint, content).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content;

        return responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }

    throw new OAuthClientException("Token request failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
}
```

This will send the code to the OP and get an access token, ID token, and perhaps a refresh token back in exchange. The important parts of this code are:

- The contents are form URL-encoded *not* JSON. This is a common mistake.
- The *same* redirect URI that was sent previously is included again. This is to match up the two requests at the OP.
- The `grant_Type` is *alway* `authorization_code`.
- The client authenticates somehow. In this case, by including the same `client_id` in the request as was previously sent together with a secret in the `client_secret` form element.
- The HTTP method used (as I said above) is a POST, not a GET. This too is a common mistake.

In my example above, I redirect back to the default, `HomeController`. Now, that if statement's else condition executes. In this, it can find the tokens:

```cs
<div>
    @if(Session.Count == 0) {
        // ...
    } else {
        @if(Session["id_token"] != null) {
            <div>
                ID Token:<br>
                <pre>@Session["id_token"]</pre>
            </div>
        }

        @if(Session["access_token"] != null) {            
            <div>
                Access Token:<br>            
                <pre>@Session["access_token"]</pre>                
            </div>
        }

        @if(Session["refresh_token"] != null) {
            <div>
                Refresh Token:<br>                
                <pre>@Session["refresh_token"]</pre>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

The example is more elaborate than this, but it hopefully gives you an idea. Go through that, check the README, and have fun learning more about OpenID Connect!

Answer (score 5):

Not enough reputation to add a comment to the IdentityServer4 answer, so I'll just mention it here.

IS4 will no longer be free for commercial uses:
[The Future of IdentityServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/10/01/the-future-of-identityserver)

> The current version (IdentityServer4 v4.x) will be the last version we work on as free open source. We will keep supporting IdentityServer4 until the end of life of .NET Core 3.1 in November 2022.
>
> To continue our work, we have formed a new company Duende Software, and IdentityServer4 will be rebranded as Duende IdentityServer. Duende IdentityServer will contain all new feature work and will target .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 (and all versions beyond).
>
> This new product will remain open source but will be offered with a dual license (RPL and commercial). The RPL (reciprocal public license) keeps Duende IdentityServer free if you are also doing free open source work. If you are using Duende IdentityServer in a commercial scenario, then a commercial license will be required. We offer a variety of ways to license Duende IdentityServer in an attempt to accommodate the different company sizes and usage models. Including an RPL license is important to us because it allows us to recognize and express our gratitude to the open source community and our contributors.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add some configuration in different places. I'll try to show all the puzzles pieces you need.
In my example, I'm going to use the public demo version of IdentityServer4 for OIDC, so you can compare with a working version.

**API**
In any controller (or method), add the `[Authorize]` attribute, so this will require a valid authentication.
You can also add a policy, if you want to be more specific with the possible actions that a user can do. Something like:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Read")]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HelloWorldsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup.cs`, you'll need to add a similar configuration like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io";
        options.Audience = "api";
    });

    // In case you want to work with policies
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Read", policy => policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api"));
    });
```

For the above configuration to compile, you should add the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`.

In the `Configure` method of the `Startup.cs`, you'll need to add `app.UseAuthentication();` just before `app.UseAuthorization();`.

**MVC**
In any controller (or method), add the `[Authorize]` attribute. Whenever the user of your MVC application hits a method with this attribute, the login process will be triggered automatically.
To demonstrate this, I'll add this attribute to a method:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy()
{
    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ApiClient");
    var apiResult = await httpClient.SendAsync(
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/helloworlds"),
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    if (apiResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await apiResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ViewData.Add("apiResult", content); // Just to demonstrate
    }

    return View();
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup.cs`, you'll need to add a similar configuration like this:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddTransient<BearerTokenHandler>();

services
    .AddHttpClient("ApiClient", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenHandler>();

services.AddHttpClient("IDPClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://demo.identityserver.io");
});

services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io";
        options.ClientId = "interactive.confidential";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.Scope.Add("api");
    });
```

For the above configuration to compile, you should add the NuGet packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`.

In the `Configure` method of the `Startup.cs`, you'll need to add `app.UseAuthentication();` just before `app.UseAuthorization();`.

Since the `BearerTokenHandler` is fairly big, you can copy this from [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/KevinDockx/SecuringAspNetCore3WithOAuth2AndOIDC/blob/master/Finished%20sample/src/ImageGallery.Client/HttpHandlers/BearerTokenHandler.cs). You'll need a NuGet package reference for `IdentityModel`.
This repository also contains a full working example of the setup that you ask for.

---

Finally, you probably want to give the users a possibility to logout.
You can do this by adding a link in your view:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
}
```

The matching controller method for this:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
{
    return SignOut(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

---

That should be it. Hopefully you're able to follow along with all the puzzle pieces.
Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Setup IdentifyServer4: IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET

You can find documentation on how to use IdentifyServer4 here:
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_aspnetcore_and_apis.html

Some of the functionality IdentityServer4 provides are:

> **Authentication as a Service**
>
> > Centralized login logic and workflow for all of your applications (web, native, mobile, services). IdentityServer is an officially certified implementation of OpenID Connect.

> **Single Sign-on / Sign-out**
>
> > Single sign-on (and out) over multiple application types.

> **Access Control for APIs**
> Issue access tokens for APIs for various types of clients, e.g. server to server, web applications, SPAs and native/mobile apps.

> **Federation Gateway**
>
> > Support for external identity providers like Azure Active Directory, Google, Facebook etc. This shields your applications from the details of how to connect to these external providers.

> **Focus on Customization**
>
> > The most important part - many aspects of IdentityServer can be customized to fit your needs. Since IdentityServer is a framework and not a boxed product or a SaaS, you can write code to adapt the system the way it makes sense for your scenarios.

> **Mature Open Source**
>
> > IdentityServer uses the permissive Apache 2 license that allows building commercial products on top of it. It is also part of the .NET Foundation which provides governance and legal backing.
> > Free and Commercial Support